# Having an optional parameter in a function

Tags: vb.net

Just a very quick question: I want to create a function with an optional parameter because I can't find a need for a parameter in the function. As a result I have coded the following function in visual basic:

```
Sub characterListLength(ByVal Optional)
    Dim rowCount As Integer
    Dim endOfArray As Boolean
    While endOfArray = False
        If dataArray(0, rowCount) And dataArray(1, rowCount) = "" Then
            arrayLength = rowCount
            endOfArray = True
        Else
            rowCount += 1
        End If
    End While



End Sub
```

However on the first line:

```
Sub characterListLength(ByVal Optional)
```

There is an error where an identifier is expected where the code says (ByVal Optional). I am not sure how to fix this error and have the optional parameter. If anyone could explain what else I need to do to fix it, that would be very useful.

Comment: `Sub characterListLength(Optional Name As String = "Foo")` the NAME is optional but the procedure will use "foo" as a default

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need an actual variable, something like:

```
Sub characterListLength(Optional ByVal optionalNumber As Integer = 0)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you said:

> because I can't find a need for a parameter in the function

Then use method without parameters:

```
Sub characterListLength()
    'Here your code
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to give the parameter a name and switch the order of the keywords

```
Sub characterListLength(Optional ByVal p = Nothing)
```

Answer (score 0):

A better "dot-nettier" alternative to optional parameters is to use overloaded methods. Consider following:

```
Overloads Sub ShowMessage()
    ShowMessage("This is the default alter message")
End Sub

Overloads Sub ShowMessage(ByVal Message As String)
    Console.WriteLine(Message)
End Sub
```

Written like this you can call the above method both ways:

```
ShowMessage() 'will display default message
ShowMessage("This is custom message") 'will display method from the parameter
```

**Demo: http://dotnetfiddle.net/OOi26i**